# Dangerous C function with different prototype is possible

Tags: c, function, linker

Here's a question that's pretty special and one I've never been aware of before. Apparently I can create a function in C that differs from its function prototype in the passing parameters. The only requirement is that the function must not know the function prototype at compile time.

In my minimal example, I created the following header Test.h:

```
int Test(int);
```

I also created the following main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Test.h"

int main()
{
    int a = Test(5);
    int b = Test(5);
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

When I use this Test.c, an error occurs when compiling, as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Test.h"

void Test(void)
{
    printf("HW\n");
}
```

If I write Test.c like this, the program is compiled, linked and is executable. Of course, the variable a has `a` seemingly arbitrary value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Test(void)
{
    printf("HW\n");
}
```

Why can this program be linked and where does the return parameter come from, for example?
This also seems very dangerous if something like this happens accidentally in larger code.

Quick additional info, when I use the same code in a C++ project, there are Linker Errors. So if I use main.cpp and Test.cpp instead of main.c and Test.c. Here things seem to be handled differently with the left. But I would also have been surprised, since C++ has function overloading.

Comment: Mismatching function declaration and definition leads to *undefined behavior*. Proper unit-testing and code-review is the solution for cases like that. Perhaps there are static code analysis tools that can help as well. But ultimately it's the responsibility of the programmers to make sure it doesn't happen.

Comment: As @Someprogrammerdude already said, in C if you mismatch declaration and definition you'll have problem. It is **programmer responsibility** to guarantee that both comply. Anyway C++ use decorations to distinguish between polymorphic functions, adding symbols after function names they are different for functions with different parameters. Also in MS C variant using `__stdcall` convention some decoration is added to the function name (an @ sign followed by the parameters bytes used). If you're using a compiler implementing that convention you'll get the same error from linker.

Comment: C doesn't just let you shoot yourself in the foot, sometimes it'll hand you the gun to do it with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior is undefined, as you have observed.

The reason you do not get an error is the linker has no information about the calling convention used in **Test.c** and **main.c** the only information is the symbol name `Test` and the type of reference (function call).

Here is a possible sequence of events:

- The `main` function calls the `Test` function, which probably behaves as expected: it calls `printf` which should print `HW` and a newline, then it returns without a return value.
- `main` then retrieves the return value it expects to have been stored in the conventional place where it should have been put by `Test`, in general, for an `int` return type, this is a register, and `main` calls `printf`
  to print this value.
- There is a good chance the value printed is `3` because `printf` returned `3` as an `int`, thus it stored 3 in the proper register, and `Test` probably did not change the register between the `printf` call and its own return statement (no guarantee of that).

You can investigate more by making the compiler produce the assembly source code with `-s` or `-S`, or play with [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org)

Compiling the code as C++ does produce an error because unlike C, C++ stores the argument types and class information along with the function names to handle overloading (it constructs synthetic names in a process called *mangling*) so when you link the **main.o** object file with the incorrect **Test.o**, the function names do not match and you get a missing symbol error.

Your example is a very good example of potential problems when linking multiple modules. The programmer(s) should adhere to good practice for mitigating this issue:

- all functions exported from a source file must be declared in a corresponding header file, and
- that header file must be included in source files that use the functions and the source file that defines them.

Modern compilers such as **gcc** and **clang** support warnings to to try and enforce this approach. You should always compile all source files with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` which define these:

- `-Wmissing-prototypes` (C and Objective-C only)

  Warn if a global function is defined without a previous prototype declaration. This warning is issued even if the definition itself provides a prototype. Use this option to detect global functions that do not have a matching prototype declaration in a header file. This option is not valid for C++ because all function declarations provide prototypes and a non-matching declaration declares an overload rather than conflict with an earlier declaration. Use `-Wmissing-declarations` to detect missing declarations in C++.
- `-Wmissing-variable-declarations` (C and Objective-C only)

  Warn if a global variable is defined without a previous declaration. Use this option to detect global variables that do not have a matching extern declaration in a header file.
- `-Wmissing-declarations`

  Warn if a global function is defined without a previous declaration. Do so even if the definition itself provides a prototype. Use this option to detect global functions that are not declared in header files. In C, no warnings are issued for functions with previous non-prototype declarations; use `-Wmissing-prototypes` to detect missing prototypes. In C++, no warnings are issued for function templates, or for inline functions, or for functions in anonymous namespaces.

Comment: Yes `3` is correct. Good explanation, thank you.

Comment: You have omitted any mention of good practice for mitigating this issue: All functions exported from a source file are declared in a corresponding header file, and that header file is included in source files that use the functions **and** the source file that defines them.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: good point, I amended amended the answer to make this recommendation more explicit.

Comment: I noticed the behavior when I used the C standard library newlib. Doesn't provide any OS interface itself and you have to write functions to which it links. Unfortunately, the documentation [https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html](https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html) under 2.1 specifies different transfer parameters than are actually passed in the newlib.

Comment: @userName: there is a special case for the `main` function which can be defined with different prototypes, but what other functions are you referring to?

Comment: @chqrlie _sbrk a function that reserves heap memory. It is needed to use `malloc()` or `calloc()`. Or _write a function that writes to a file.

Comment: @userName What do you mean by "different transfer parameters"?  [`write()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/write.html) is a POSIX-standard function and [`sbrk()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sbrk.html) also used to be standardized under POSIX.  Those functions originated on Unix systems that predate standardized C.  The underscore versions `_sbrk()` and `_write()` are usually alternate symbol names for the POSIX-standard functions that are reserved identifiers under standardized C.

Comment: @Andrew Henle I chose a bad word here. By "transfer parameters" I mean "arguments".
Yes, it is POSIX, but newlib is more for RTOS or systems with no OS. With this library it is not unusual that you have to write your own interfaces and this is also designed for that.